# Understanding `parent.parent` when a frameset is nested in an iframe

Tags: javascript, silverlight, iframe, visio, frames

I'm trying to understand `parent.parent` object in the context of a `<frameset>` nested in an `<iframe>`. It seems to behave differently from a `<frameset>` nested in a `window`. If you drop a `<frameset>` page into an `<iframe>` I expect `parent.parent` to refer to the `<iframe>`'s window - but this appears to not be correct?

```
Parent Doc  <== parent.parent.someFunction tries to execute here
|-Iframe    <== this is where I'm expecting parent.parent to target and where parent.parent.someFunction exists
  |-Frameset
    |-Frame <== Javascript executes here calling parent.parent.someFunction
```

... It appears that `parent.parent` refers to the document which contains the `<iframe>` and not the `<iframe>` itself which I would have expected.

How can I target `parent.parent.someFunction` in the `<iframe>`? In my case I need to somehow proxy `parent.parent` as I cannot easily edit the code containing the `parent.parent` (see why in my *Use Case* below)

Further research brought me to these pages:

[JavaScript: Windows and Frames](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/%3Fpage%3D7)

[image: http://archive.oreilly.com/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/graphics/js4_1304.gif]

[Javascript: The Definitive Guide:](https://books.google.ie/books?id=4RChxt67lvwC&lpg=PA356&ots=th_7HkLTv8&dq=parent.parent%20in%20iframe%20frameset%20frame&pg=PA357#v=onepage&q=parent.parent&f=false)

**Page 356:**

> If a frame is contained within another frame that is contained with a top-level window, that frame can refer to the top-level window as `parent.parent`
>
> `<iframe>` elements have a `contentWindow` property that refers to the Window object of the frame

### My Use Case

I want to explain why I want to do this.

My specific use case: I'm trying to display a web page generated from a *Visio > Export to Web Page Complete* inside of an `<iframe>`.

The code that is exported from Visio uses `<frameset>` and `<frame>` tags to implement the menu, widget and content areas of the page:

```
</head>
<frameset id="frmstOuter" cols="237,*">
    <frame src="0.1_files/toolbar.htm" name="frmToolbar" id="frmToolbar" title="This frame contains tools for manipulating your drawing." frameborder="6" bordercolor="#999999" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" >
    <frame src="0.1_files/png_1.htm" name="frmDrawing" title="This frame contains the pages of your drawing." marginheight="10" marginwidth="10" onload="if (parent.isUpLevel) FramePageLoaded()" >

    <noframes>
        <body>

            <h1>KPI Request Process</h1>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="0.1_files/png_1.htm">KPI Change Request Process</a></li>
            <li><a href="0.1_files/png_2.htm">KPI Assessment</a></li>
            <li><a href="0.1_files/png_3.htm">Activate KPI</a></li>

            </ul>
        </body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
```

If I load this in IE, it loads into a Silverlight application. The use of Silverlight seems to all depend on `parent.isUpLevel` - this is set to `true` if a Silverlight supported browser is detected.

I've written some JavaScript which uses the Proxy Design Pattern to hook in some `before`, `compose` and `after` events so that I can customise application behaviour without editing the original source (as it's generated). I'm doing this as I want to be able to use the Visio export code within another web page and to have the events within the Visio diagram trigger events within my application. For example, clicking on a process in the diagram will filter a view in my application.

So I bring the above page into my application using:

```
<iframe id="ProcessExplorer" style="width:100%; height: 800px; border: none" src="/Content/Processes/0.1.htm"></iframe>
```

And as soon as I do this, I get the error message:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'FindShapeXML'
```

Which points to this line:

```
var shapeNode = parent.parent.FindShapeXML (pageID, shapeID);
```

This line of code runs fine when I load the frameset in its original page instead of putting that page into an `<iframe>`.

Based on the articles above, I tried to monkey-patch `parent.parent` as follows but it has not solved my issue:

```
parent.parent = parent.parent.document.getElementById('ProcessExplorer').contentWindow;
```

... I'm guessing this doesn't work as `parent.parent` is a protected object? If I try to set `parent.parent = 'somestring'` it has no effect either...

Is there any way to achieve what I want here - i.e. to proxy `parent.parent` so that it points to my `iframe#ProcessExplorer` instead of the `top` window???

Comment: Excellent formulation of the question. In fact, I stumbled on the same with broken Visio publishing to <iframe>. Nobody can give a hint?

Comment: Some people advise in this situation using $(this).closest("someClass"). Maybe $(this).closest("ProcessExplorer") will work?

Comment: @BorisZinchenko I'll dig out the code for this tomorrow and have a look!